# can we create separate view files in django app?

Tags: python, django

In my django app, i have user,employee,admin modules.

do I can create seperate views.py files for user,employee and admin

eg:
i have folder called "AdminFolder" and I have added seperate adminView.py in it

is it allowed in django?

Comment: Yes you can create separate view, urls and admin files but you have to take care of imports in each file.

Comment: Can i create such that my app contains one common url and different view files for different modules

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You may create some folders for separating `views` files and just show the path for files

Comment: Thank dude, appreciated

Comment: Can you please tell me how i call access adminViews.py (AdminFolder/adminViews.py) from urls.py(myapp/urls.py).  I tried to import Admin Folder from urls.py but got error.

Comment: It should be like `from myapp.urls import View`